# "Function declarations cannot be nested inside a statement" - IE in strict mode error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, use-strict

In a `"use strict"` application, I'm using `document.createTreeWalker` to traverse a DOM tree. After I get the tree from the browser I use a while loop to push the values into an array. The code is an upgrade to the excellent [Letteringjs.com](http://letteringjs.com/) plugin, and my version can be seen in action [here](http://sbnwebsolutions.com/).

```
function injector(t, splitter, klass, after) {
    var inject = '', n,
        tree = [],
        styleStack = [],
        splitIndex = 0,

        styleAndSplit = function (node, splitter, klass, after) {
            var particles = $(node).text().split(splitter);

            // Wrap each particle with parent style tags if present
            for (var j = 0, len = particles.length; j < len; j++) {
                var str = '<span class="'+klass+((splitIndex++)+1)+'">'+particles[j]+'</span>'+after;

                for (var k = styleStack.length - 1, style; style = styleStack[k--];) {
                    str =   '<' + style.tagName.toLowerCase() + (style.className ? ' class="' + style.className + '"' : '') + '>' +
                            str + 
                            '</' + style.tagName.toLowerCase() + '>'
                }
                inject += str;
            }
        },

        Walker /* Texas Ranger */ = document.createTreeWalker(
            t,
            NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL,
            { acceptNode: function (node) {
                // Keep only text nodes and style altering tags
                if (node.nodeType === 3 || node.nodeType === 1 && !!node.tagName &&
                   (node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'i' || 
                        node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'b' || 
                            node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'u' ||
                                node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span')) {

                    return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
                } else {
                    return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
                }
            }},
            false
        );

    while (n = Walker.nextNode()) tree.push(n);

    // This loop traverses all of the nodes in the order they appear within the HTML tree
    // It will then stack up nested styling tags accordingly
    for (var i = 0, node; node = tree[i++];) {
        if (node.nodeType === 1) {
            styleStack.push(node);
        } else {
            // Get rid of nodes containing only whitespace (newlines specifically)
            if ($.trim(node.nodeValue).length) {
                while (styleStack.length && node.parentNode !== styleStack[styleStack.length - 1]) { styleStack.pop(); }
                styleAndSplit(node, splitter, klass, after);    
            }
        }
    }       

    $(t).empty().append(inject);        
}
```

This code works in Firefox, Chrome and mobile browsers too. But IE9 & IE10 don't play nice.

Both break execution on the `while (n = Walker.nextNode()) tree.push(n);` line, prompting:

> SCRIPT1047: In strict mode, function declarations cannot be nested
>   inside a statement or block. They may only appear at the top level or
>   directly inside a function body.

EDIT: this is the [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/br230269%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) as to what should throw this error:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var index = null;
for (index in arr) {
    function myFunc() {};
}
```

EDIT: But that doesn't make sense, because I am not declaring a function, I am only executing one. Regardless though, I followed fred02138's suggestion to remove the `styleAndSplit` function declaration (I simply replaced the call with the function code, and erased the declaration) - but **it didn't mend the error**.

Is there a different way to traverse a `TreeWalker`, or is there a workaround for IE (without losing strict mode)?

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Comment: What about `styleAndSplit`? Isn't that a nested function declaration?

Comment: @fred02138 that doesn't make sense though, since I am using this pattern with `use-strict` in other parts of my application in it doesn't spawn an error. What more, it only happens in IE. I'll give it a try though. And let you know.

Comment: @fred02138 it still breaks on the same line with the same error.

Comment: @scunliffe It was worth bumping into this error just to have an excuse to post this comment here, but I'd still like a decent solution nonetheless ;)

Comment: any chance you can post the generated code that appears in the browser - in Chrome/Firefox etc. With this we might be able to see what IE is choking on.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm running this locally with grunt, that is the code running in the browser - or did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function as variable will resolve the issue for me.

If you are making any asynchronous call please